# In perl, is there a way to make subroutines print their name and arguments when called?

Tags: perl, internals

I need to quickly understand which subroutines are being called in a mess of spaghetti code perl modules.

I could write a script to go through all the modules and add code to print out the subroutine name and arguments at the start of every subroutine.

But is there a way to override the internal perl 'subroutine' mechanism itself to do this?

The code is running under mod_perl so I can't easily use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to Devel::Trace and the Apache docs, but using Moose as @cnicutar describes below is the easiest way by far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[`Moose::MethodModifiers`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0000/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod)**. I don't know much about `Moose`, but from the manual I can see you can do it. Here goes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.010;
use strict;
use Moose;

sub sub_one {
    say "I am sub one!";
}

sub sub_two {
    say "Guess who!";
}

# Note that the name of the function being modified isn't passed in in
# any way

for my $func qw(sub_one sub_two) {
    around $func => sub {
        my $orig = shift;

        say "Running ${func}(@_)";

        # call the original sub
        my $self = shift;
        $self->$orig(@_);
    }
}

sub_one(21, 12);
sub_two();
```

This produces something like

```
cnicutar@aiur:~$ perl method_modifiers.pl
Running sub_one(21 12)
I am sub one!
Running sub_two()
Guess who!
```

Please note I'm only a beginner so be cautious about that code.

Answer (score 4):

[Devel:Trace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aTrace) will show subroutine calls and arguments. It will also show every line of code that is executed, which may be more verbose than you need.

```
perl -d:Trace program
```

[Devel::DumpTrace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aDumpTrace) will be even more verbose, showing the **values** of variables as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the code through [NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) when when [running under Apache via mod_perl](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf/Apache.pm)

Answer (score 1):

I know you say you "can't easily use the debugger" because you're running under mod_perl, but there are some options for doing just that described here:

http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/debug.html#Non_Interactive_Perl_Debugging_under_mod_perl